# Variable comparison

Tags: .net, cil, intermediate-language

The following C#-snippet:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 1;
if (x == y)
    Console.Write("True");
```

Generates this MSIL:

```
.locals init (
            [0] int32 x,
            [1] int32 y,
            [2] bool CS$4$0000)
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: ldc.i4.1 
L_0002: stloc.0 
L_0003: ldc.i4.1 
L_0004: stloc.1 
L_0005: ldloc.0 
L_0006: ldloc.1 
L_0007: ceq 
L_0009: ldc.i4.0 
L_000a: ceq 
L_000c: stloc.2 
L_000d: ldloc.2 
L_000e: brtrue.s L_001b
L_0010: ldstr "True"
L_0015: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(string)
L_001a: nop 
L_001b: ret
```

Why is there two `ceq` calls?

Thanks

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot of things that were messing with my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `ceq` opcode compares the result of the first one to `0`.  (`false`)

This result is then put in a variable, loaded from the variable, and, if it was `true`, the `WriteLine` call is skipped.

I would assume that Release mode generates more efficient code, but I'm too lazy to check.

Comment: Yes, from what i can tell, release mode generates more efficent il-code. There is not even a call to `ceq`. Is this because the compiler knows that x and z are constants?

Comment: @alexn: Correct.  The compiler optimizes out the constant comparisons.  If you don't want it to, you can write `Math.Max(1, 1)`, which is not a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 2):

About comparing values with `ceq` From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ceq.aspx):

> If they are equal, the integer value 1 (int32) is pushed onto the evaluation stack; otherwise 0 (int32) is pushed onto the evaluation stack.

The second `ceq` checks whether the first comparison failed, if so, it jumps to the exit point.